# Docker compose is failing when copying npmrc

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am getting this error when trying to run my docker with docker compose

> => ERROR [6/9] COPY .npmrc .npmrc
> 0.0s  => ERROR [7/9] ADD package.json /Users/gs/Documents/Dev/DockerDi  0.0s

```yaml
version: "3"
   
services:
  gs-service:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./gs/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
   
  ui-service:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./ui/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
```

Here is the detail of the Dockerfile which is failing. This is a subdirectory. For example `/user/gs/dockerexperiment/ui`

- docker-compose file is in parent directory. For example
  `/user/gs/dockerexperiment`
- Dockerfile is in subdirectory. For    example
  `/user/gs/dockerexperiment/ui`

I know something is going wrong with the class path but I am having a difficult time figuring out what I am missing

Comment: 1) Did you paste the full error message? It does not contain any valuable info to understand what is going wrong. 2) you are not giving the structure of your project. We cannot know if the files you copy are there 3) (probably not related) please read [docker best practice](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy) where you will learn that using `COPY` is preferred to `ADD` in most cases. You should change the instruction when copying your `package.json` file.

Comment: failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to compute cache key: "/package.json" not found: not found

Comment: Package.json does exist inside /user/gs/dockerexperiment/ui

Comment: The docker runs fine if I run it directly inside the directory i.e inside the UI directory

Comment: The left-hand side of `COPY` instructions is always relative to the `build: { context: }` directory (or the directory that's an argument to `docker build`); this isn't necessarily the directory the Dockerfile is in.

Comment: @DavidMaze: Can you elaborate more on this?

Answer (score 3):

A Dockerfile operates on a *build context*; this is a copy of the directory tree you name as the `build: { context: }` in the `docker-compose.yml` file (or, if you're using `docker build` directly, its directory argument).

```yaml
build:
  context: .
```

In the Dockerfile, any `COPY` (or `ADD`) instructions are interpreted as relative to this directory tree.  (If it looks like an absolute path, it's still relative to this directory; any `..` path steps that would step outside this directory get ignored.)

```sh
COPY package*.json ./
# copies ./package.json, relative to the context directory
```

But, you clarify in a comment, this isn't actually where your files are.  Relative to the `docker-compose.yml` file, you need `./ui/package.json`; the Dockerfile is also in the same subdirectory.

The Dockerfile you show doesn't seem to need any content from outside its immediate tree, so the easiest way to address this is to set the `ui` directory as the build context:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  ui:
    build: ./ui
    # Same as
    # build:
    #   context: ./ui
    #   dockerfile: Dockerfile # relative to the context directory
    ports:
      - 8085:8085
```

In the Dockerfile, you can remove the duplicate `ADD package.json` line, and you should remove the dangerous `RUN npm set config` line.  You can also set a much shorter `WORKDIR`, something like `/app` would be typical.

If you don't want to change the `docker-compose.yml` file, the other possible change is to adjust the Dockerfile so that its `COPY` paths are relative to the (parent) build-context directory.

```sh
COPY ui/package*.json .
```

The advantage of doing this is that you can access files from the other application, if you need to, or you can store shared files in that parent directory.

```sh
FROM node:14

# Add the public TLS key for our internal repository
# (from the parent directory)
COPY repository.example.com.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
RUN update-ca-certificates

WORKDIR /app

# Also get our local npm configuration (from the parent directory)
COPY .npmrc .

# Install the ./ui application
COPY ui/package*.json .
RUN npm ci
COPY ui/src ./src
EXPOSE 8085
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```